# How to make same sized views in tablelayout if each row contains different number of views?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout, tablerow

[image]

I created 4 gif image buttons and added them to a list of gif image buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    GifImageButton myButton = new GifImageButton();
    myButton.setBackgroundResource(drawables[i]); // add some drawable to the button background
    myButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
    listButtons.add(myButton);
}
```

Then I created a tablelayout (rows = 2, columns = 3) programmatically and added it to my layout:

```
MyTableLayout tableLayout = new MyTableLayout(this);
tableLayout.createTableLayoutOfButtons(tableRows /*=2*/, tableCols /*=3*/, listButtons);
mylinearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

my MyTableLayout class is:

```
public class MyTableLayout extends TableLayout {

    public MyTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // indexListButtons is the current index of the listButtons elements. so as long as there are buttons, we will add them to the table rows
    int indexListButtons = 0;
    public void createTableLayoutOfButtons(int numRows, int numCols, List<GifImageButton> listButtons) {
        setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
            tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j, ++indexListButtons) {
                // indices 0, 1, 2, 3
                if (indexListButtons < listButtons.size()) {
                    tableRow.addView(listButtons.get(indexListButtons));
                }
                // indices 4, 5 don't exist
                else {
                    // not enough buttons
                }
            }
            addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the code so I get the 'expected result'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [LayoutSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_span) attribute in the TableRow.LayoutParams that you can set on the TableRow children, namely, the listButtons.get(indexListButtons). Try setting that to 1. Otherwise you could try inserting empty Views for the other columns.

Comment: I tried the layoutspan but it didn't work.. I wanted to try to avoid of inserting empty views but it solved it! I needed to add a view with the specific params of the view. thanks!